# Would a normal spider spawner work if I built a farm meant for cave spiders

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found a spider spawner in my survival world and am wondering if I could build a farm meant for a cave spider spawner would it work with the normal spider spawner?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's hard to say without a specific model, question could be edited to include that model or ask what features would break it

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely without proper adaptations. Cave spider is 0.7 block wide and 0.5 block tall. Regular spider is 1.4 block wide and 0.9 block tall. That means if the collection channels are 1 block wide, regular spiders won't fit; if any passages are through a slab-sized gap, regular spiders won't fit.

The general concept should work, but you will need to adjust the sizes of passages.